# Cv2 module not found in tensorflow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I Installed opencv and cv2 in anaconda and created a tensorflow environment for imageprocessing.

tensorflow is present in

```
c:/Users/mayank singh/local/conda/conda/envs/tfdeeplearning/lib/site-packages
```

And cv2 is prensent in

```
c:/Programdata/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages
```

cv2 is working independently in jupyter notebook but shows error "module not found" after activating tensorflow

Comment: I have no idea why, and I'm not sure you've provided enough information. That being said as a developer be *very* wary about using spaces in your file paths

Comment: cv2 is working independently in jupyter notebook but shows error "module not found" in tensorflow